# Detach machine that is no longer in use from Ubuntu Advantage / UA

Tags: ubuntu-advantage

similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379645/ubuntu-advantage-subscriptions-show-3-machine-but-only-1-machine-known-how-to-g), How do I remove machines from my subscription if I can no longer access them?

Background: I have a dead OS build attached to my UA subscription. In fact I reinstalled with a new/updated OS (22.04.01 LTS) on the same hardware and attached it to my subscription. Now it says I've attached 2x machines, when in reality it is only 1x.

Thanks in advance for help.